# Find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$ and $a+b+c=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find  $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4\;\;\;{\rm  and}\;\;\;a+b+c=3$$

Seeing $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$,I substituted $a=2\cos{A}$,$b=2\cos{B},c=\cos{C}$ with $A+B+C=180°$.
Therefore,$cosA+cosB+cosC=\frac 32$ have thousands of solution. What to do now? Please help me.

Comment: (1,1,1) works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we put $c=3-a-b$ we get quadratic equation on $a$ with parameter $b$, if $b \ne 2$:

$$(2-b)a^2-a(b^2-5b+6)+(2b^2-6b+5)=0$$

which has a solution iff it discriminat is nonnegative: $$(b-2)(b+2)(b-1)^2\geq 0$$
so $b>2$ or $b=1$...

- Clearly if $b=1$ we get $a^2-2a+1=0$ so $a=1$ and then $c=1$.
- If $b>2$ then with similar reason say on $b$ we get $a>2$ or $c>2$ which is impossibile.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\cos(C)+\cos(B)+\cos(A)\le \frac{3}{2}$$ and this Comes from
$$\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)=1+\frac{r}{R}$$

Comment: $cos(A)+cos(B)+cos(C)=1+\frac{2r}{R}$? Is it a well-known property? I didn't know that. By the way, thanks.

Comment: I think it is known, see on AOPS Website.

Comment: See my little correction!